# Why Unordered_Map hashing is too slow then my simple array hash

Tags: c++, hash

Well I am saying this third consecutive time that
I have solved [UVa 100 - The 3n + 1 problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36) 
I have first implemented simple hash by creating a array of size 1000000 and then I store result in that array, then I tried C++ Unordered Map for hashing and time difference between both of them are too huge for same input

here is my source code

[I have tried pasting my code here but every time it shattered so I paste here Sorry :(](https://shrib.com/mdpbEBGj)

here is the time taken by
1. Simple array
2. Simple Map
3. unordered map

[image: Screenshot of my terminal]

So why there is too much time difference between unordered map and simple array. I know simple map is slow but the difference is about 3 min :(

Comment: Regarding code shattering: replace tabs with spaces and try again.

Comment: Unordered map would be much slower than arrays because it needs memory allocations. But it is significantly slower in case possibly because default hash function is colliding a lot.

Comment: What does the profiler say?  (My guess would be the cost of allocations and the lack of locality, but that's just a guess.)

Comment: I have not ever used profiler in my life and I have to search about it a lot before implementing and saying about this so give me some time :(

Answer (score 2):

Given that you can use an array interchangably with a hash table, definitely the array will be a lot faster. `m[n]` on an array is just pointer arithmetic and a dereference, versus on an `unordered_map` involves calculating a hash, looking up in a bucket, and doing some equality comparisons. Also, the way you're looking up your indices gives you massive cache locality benefits in the array which will not apply in the `unordered_map.` I would fully expect the array to win every time - it just necessarily has to do less work.

That said, your `unordered_map` implementation could be improved a lot:

```
while(n != 1) {
    if(m1[n] != 0) {
        res += m1[n];
    }
}
```

That's doing two lookups for the same index twice. You should do it just once (which you do for `std::map` btw...):

```
while (n != 1) {
    auto it = m1.find(n);
    if (it != m.end()) {
        res += it->second;
    }
}
```

And same for your printing loop:

```
if (res < m1[i]) res = m1[i];
```

Should be:

```
int m1i = m1[i];
if (res < m1i) res = m1i;
```

And lastly, this line is undefined behavior:

```
i = ( i + j ) - ( j = i );
                ^^^^^^^^^
```

The modification of `j` in the 2nd expression is unsequenced with the respect to the access of it in the first expression.

Comment: i = ( i + j ) - ( j = i ); This line is a one line swap but I will now not include this in my practice

Comment: `auto it = m1.find(n);`
Also if I am finding value using find function then why I a creating a hash??

Comment: @geeksoul it tries to do a one-line swap, but since it's undefined behavior, who knows what it actually does. Could work. Could not work. So you absolutely need to change that practice. Just do std::swap(i, j);

Comment: @geeksoul `m1[n]` also does a hash lookup. It's basically a `find()` that if it doesn't find anything, then inserts something with a default value.

Comment: if m1[n] is also a find then definitely it should be slower then arr1[n] because it is just arr+n ??
if all the above is true then why to use unordered_map?

Comment: @geeksoul You use it when you can't use an array. What if your keys are non-contiguous integers? You're not just going to just make a HUGE array. What if your keys can be negative? What if your keys aren't even numbers?

Comment: @Barry thanks I got it. In my case better to use array and if my hash table has size of 10^9 use map. Am I right?

Comment: @geeksoul The size doesn't matter. Only the distribution of keys. If you need to store every integer from 0 to 10^9, definitely use array. If you only need to store like 1, 50, 2000, and 10^9... definitely use a hashtable since that would be a ridiculous waste of memory otherwise.