# unordered_map really slow even with cheap hash (profiled)

Tags: c++, performance, profiling, unordered-map

I try to profile a CPU-intensive part of my program.

It stunned me, **unordered_map**'s **isContain**, **insert**, and **remove** are **really slow**.

Here is a real example of result from profiling:-

```
Physic_Object* cave = ... it is a function argument ...
if(cave->id==3){                            //< 0.1% simple int
    int asdfdssd=0;
}
//"concaves" is MyEncapsulatorOf_unordered_map<Physic_Object*> (it is a field)
//There are about 500-1000 elements in the unordered_map.
if (phy_concaves.isContain(cave)) {         //0.8%  unordered_map "isContain" 
    phy_concaves.remove_immediate(cave);    //4.9%  unordered_map "iscontain" + "erase"
    cave->finalize_inverse();               //6.0%  a lot of unordered_map function
    delete cave;                            //0.7%  simple delete
}else {
}
```

Here is my cheap hash function.

```
//Physic_Object.h
public:virtual long hqHashCode() const override final {
    return id; 
    //id is +1 every time when new Physic_Object is create
    //I have a static int "id_runner" to track.
}
```

From the whole profile, **unordered_map**'s operations is gobbling about 70%-80% of my game.

**Question:** Is unordered_map really slow like that, or is there anything wrong about my code?
More specifically, is it common that insertion/deletion cost around 40+ simple arithmetic operation?

Here is how I create unordered_map, I don't think there is anything wrong, but provided just in case.

```
//MyEncapsulatorOf_unordered_map<K> ,  K can be pointer or value
template<typename T2> static const
    T2 * ptr(T2 const& obj) { return &obj; } //turn reference into pointer!
template<typename T2> static
    T2 * ptr(T2 * obj) { return obj; } //obj is already pointer, return it!
template< class T2>class structTPtr1 {
    public:
    std::size_t operator()(T2 const& t) const{
        std::size_t h1 = ptr(t)->hqHashCode();
        return h1;
    }
};
template< class T2>class structTPtr2 {
    public: bool operator() (const T2 & t1, const T2&t2) const {
        return t1 == t2;
    }
};
public:std::unordered_set<K, structTPtr1<K>, structTPtr2<K>>main;
```

Note that I ran in debug mode from visual c++, but release mode yields a similar result.

[Why Unordered_Map hashing is too slow then my simple array hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410075/why-unordered-map-hashing-is-too-slow-then-my-simple-array-hash) seems to be the most related question, but it doesn't indicate/profile performance of unordered_map.

I don't think it is about gcc either.  Therefore this link may not relate. [Is gcc std::unordered_map implementation slow? If so - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614106/is-gcc-stdunordered-map-implementation-slow-if-so-why)

Comment: What is the distribution of your hash codes? If there's a lot of duplicate hashes that's going to be a problem. How many objects are going into the map?

Comment: No unordered_map at sight in the provided code. How do you know yiour hash function is good?

Comment: Thank, I edited my question to clarify it.     id (for hash) is 0 1 2 ... when a new object is created.  I am quite sure that there are not many collisions.

Comment: *"More specifically, is it common that insertion/deletion cost around 40+ simple arithmetic operation?"* - you've got virtual dispatch for hashing which could account for a good fraction of that, then if your table's larger than L1 cache should expect cache stalls, you may have resizing during insertions if you haven't used [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/reserve), and C++ implementations tend to use buckets with pointers to stored values, rather than storing values directly in buckets, which can be slower for small types like pointers.

Comment: You have around 1000 elements so with the simplest growth implementation for hash table (which is the STL's implementation at least for Visual Studio), you'll have the 10 LSBits at most that will contribute to the final bucket key for your map. It can be even less since buckets are expected to contain more than one element.Then, you need to reserve in advance if you know how much elements will end up in your map to avoid costly rehashes.